# Why using this@MainActivity in this code?

Tags: android, kotlin, label, this

I saw a code like this in **MainActivity** class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val languages = arrayOf("One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten")
    private var index = 0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        textSwitcher.setFactory {

            val textView = TextView(this@MainActivity) //the line I was 
                                                       //talking about.

            textView.gravity =  Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
            textView.textSize = 32f
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        }
        textSwitcher.setText(languages[index])
    }
}
```

But i didnt get it. "**this**" keyword already not represent the **MainActivity**? If so why needed the label?

I have written that code for understanding the "this" keyword.

```
class class1(c:class2){
    init{
        c.output()
    }
}
class class2{
    init{
        class1(this) // this" keyword represent the class2
    }
    fun output(){
        println("Hello.")
    }
}
fun main(){
    val x = class2()
}
```

Comment: ""this" keyword already not represent the MainActivity?" -- not necessarily. It would depend on where that line is. However, it is difficult to help you further, given that single line of code. You might consider editing your question so that your [mcve] shows the entire `MainActivity`, including the line that concerns you.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have tried to reduce the code to a minimal level but I edited.

Answer (score 2):

The line that concerns you is in a lambda expression, one that is being converted by Kotlin into [the `makeView()` function implementation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory?hl=en#makeView()) of a `ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory`. So, in the scope of that lambda expression, `this` is the `ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory`, not the `MainActivity`. So, we need the `@MainActivity` label to indicate that we want the outer `MainActivity` object's representation of `this`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/ViewSwitcher?hl=en#setfactory

Comment: I don't know why I don't understand. But I think such as. setFactory is a higher order function. If I write "this", it detect a value in HOF as a reference. Right? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @Furkan: "setFactory is a higher order function" -- not really. It is a function that takes a Java interface object as a parameter. The code here is using Kotlin SAM (single abstract method) support to convert a lambda expression into an instance of that Java interface. "it detect a value in HOF as a reference" -- sorry, but I do not know what HOF means in this context.

Comment: This is also a confusing point. How did you find that setFactory is a SAM? It doesn't write anything in Android references (like SAM or higher order function). And the SAM's that I know are Java interfaces.

Comment: I see a public class when I enter [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher) (as far as i know, a sam can not be from the class.) I dont saw Interface.

When I look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory) there is a interface, yes. But there is no setFactory method. So if it was "setFactory" in it, I would say it is SAM.  How you can say "it is SAM"?
I hope I could tell.

And I shortened HOF as the **H**igher **O**rder **F**unction.

Comment: @Furkan: "How did you find that setFactory is a SAM?" -- `setFactory()` is a method. It takes a `ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory` as a parameter. [`ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory` is a Java interface with a single abstract method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory). Hence, Kotlin SAM support can be used to create the `ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory` instance.

Comment: Thanks your answers. But there is a lot of point, that i dont understand. What does the point between the two classes mean? Why did this parameter require such use the `{}`? I can understand if you send an example that I can do with plain Kotlin. Thanks.

Comment: The point between the class names is because `ViewFactory` is defined as a nested class of `ViewSwitcher`, and that's how you typically reference a nested class's name. You don't have to define the parameter with `{ }`. You could alternatively use an anonymous object. But since it is an interface with a SAM, you can use the shortcut SAM conversion notation where it looks like a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

If that line of code is inside of `apply` lambda or inside some object or in such other cases; lambda will have reference to itself can be accessed using the same keyword `this`. So to specify the appropriate reference @ with scope name as label is specified.

So basically label is used to specify scope of outer class inside other lambdas or inner classes etc.,